# Jquery rotate, run on mouseenter, stop on mouseout

Tags: jquery, animation, hover, rotation

doing some jQuery animation for a high profile client that has to be finished by lunch

Basically what I'm trying to do is animate an object in a 360 degree circle repeatedly when it is hovered, and return the animation to its start point when the mouse leaves.

I'm using the Jquery rotate plugin http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples

I've got it to animate on mouseover, however can't, no matter how hard I try, get it to stop animating on mouse out - I'm currently messing around with intervals to try and get it to cooperate - here's my current code, what am I missing?!?!

```
    function rotation(){

    jQuery("#merm").rotate({angle:0, animateTo: 360, callback: rotation });
    }

    jQuery("#sirens").hover(
        function(){
        hoverInterval = setInterval(rotation, 1000);
        },
        function(){
            clearInterval(hoverInterval);
        }
    );
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you pop your code on jsfiddle please, then i'll take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    var t;
    $("#sirens").mouseenter(function(){
        var angle = 0;
        t = setInterval(function(){
            angle+=3;
            $("#sirens").rotate(angle);
        },50);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        clearInterval(t);
        $("#sirens").rotate(0);
    });
});
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/t4MHp/1/

Comment: awesome, I should have mentioned I need it to return to the start on mouseout, which is why I was using this particular example---- var rotation = function (){
   $("#img").rotate({
      angle:0, 
      animateTo:360, 
      callback: rotation
   });
}
rotation();

Comment: Updated to go back to 0 on mouse leave.

Answer (score 1):

Just a short info - a new version of jQueryRotate 2.2 released today supports stoping animation by calling .stopRotate() :) Hope it helps in future